# Limits of 3D Graphs with Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem when setting axis limits of 3D graphs. 
I'm using pandas to read my database files, that are just numbers (float64 format) of atmosferic discharges and wind speed.
But when setting a limit, like 1200 thunders and 80 km/h wind speed, my plot just exceeds the desired surface.
It happens with "ax.set_xlim3d","ax.set_xlim" and "plt.xlim".

My code is as below:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
y = dados['Rajada']
x = dados['Raios']
z = ((1/3080)*(np.exp(2.2507716+(0.0011096*x)+(0.0274958*y))))
ax.set_xlabel('Número de Raios',fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Rajada Máxima em Km/H',fontsize=15)
ax.set_zlabel('Taxa de Falha por Quilômetro',fontsize=15)
plt.xlim(0,1200)
plt.ylim(0,80)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap='coolwarm',hatch='/-', edgecolor='none')
```

[Image of how the graph was plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22vI.png)

Comment: I think 3D is still relatively experimental in matplotlib so maybe you just have to cut your data to fit

Comment: Unlike in 2D, matplotlib does not clip the data by the limits in 3D plots. If you do not want to show any data that is larger than a certain number you need to make sure to not plot this data to start with.